# how to use sqlite in virtual environment?

Tags: python, sql, database, sqlite, flask

how can i use sqlite database in virtual environment??
when I run my program without using virtual environment database file successfully created.
but when I run program using venv i got this type of NoSuchModuleError: Can't load plugin: sqlalchemy.dialects:sqlite3
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dlDG9.png)

how can i install sqlite in my venv i tried
pip install pysqlite3 but not solve my error

[package installed in venv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aDt46.png)

Comment: (1) What happens if you run `python -c 'import sqlite3` in the terminal while the venv is (a) active (b) inactive? (2) Please [edit] the question to include the _complete_ error traceback, for the original error and also any occurs that occur in (1).

Comment: when i run `import sqlite3` in terminal while the venv active and inactive the line execute successfully

Comment: not imported statement `import sqlite3` in my python file. thanks for help me

Comment: Add a solution and submit as answered so that other would see that it's resolved.

Answer (score 1):

my error is solved by importing the statement `import sqlite3`
[solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dn1Xd.png)

Answer (score 0):

#### how to use sqlite in virtual environment?

1. Have a sqlite3 installed in system locally from https://www.sqlite.org/download.html download `sqlite-tools-win32-x86-3400100.zip (1.90 MiB)`
2. Unzip all the files and save them in `C:\Program Files (x86)\sqlite3`
3. Add to System Environment path:

   a. sqlite3: `C:\Program Files (x86)\sqlite3\sqlite3.exe`

   b. PATH: `C:\Program Files (x86)\sqlite3`
4. In command prompt type `>sqlite3` you should get "SQLite version 3.40.1 2022-12-28 14:03:47"
5. In program include `import sqlite3`